# Unknown output from unix file command

Tags: linux, unix

I ran the [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) command against a file and got this result:

```
data (gzip compressed data, was <fd:1> from unix)
```

What does the "<fd:1> from unix" mean?

Comment: Whats the actual command that you executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fd:1 is "file descriptor 1", which means standard output.

My guess is that the file is the result of a pipe from the output of another file like `cat file|gzip - > new.gz`

I was not able to reproduce that output, but it could be that different versions of gzip handle that differently.